# On device back button the previous fragment web service call is called again

Tags: android, web-services, android-fragments

We have the following implementation:

We have a fragment e.g.: InboxFragment which has a list view of all messages.

In InboxFrgament, on load we call a web service to retrieve the latest messages from the cloud using a web service call:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_inbox, container, false);
    context = getActivity();

    //Get Messages From Cloud - web service call
    if (ON_BACK_PRESSED == 0) {
        GetMessagesFromCloud();
    }
}
```

When you tap on a message, we add a new fragment MessageDetailsFragment to the stack. We use the following function to add a new fragment:

```
public void AddFragmentToStack(Fragment newFragment, String tag) {
    FragmentTransaction ft = this.getSupportFragmentManager()
            .beginTransaction();
    ft.replace(R.id.content_frame, newFragment, tag);
    ft.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_OPEN);
    ft.addToBackStack(null);
    ft.commit();
}
```

Now this works properly. But when we hit the device back button (while we are on the MessageDetailsFragment), it takes us back to InboxFragment and the onCreateView function gets called again because of which the web service call to fetch new messages is made to server.

We don't want this web service call to happen each time when we hit back on the MessageDetailsFragment. We have a pull down to refresh implemented in the InboxFragment which is the event to download any new messages. So, we have taken a flag ON_BACK_PRESSED = 1 when MessageDetailsFragment is loaded, and in InboxFragment if this flag is set to 1, then don't make the web service call GetMessagesFromCloud().

We want to know if above is right way to prohibit the web service call as onCreateView is always called when the fragment appear. Please advise.

From our knowledge when the same implementation is done on iOS platform, on hitting back, the fragment in view is popped out and the fragment behind appears. The web service call is not made each time when you hit back because the call to web service in in DidViewLoad event. They have 2 events - DidViewLoad and DidViewAppear. So when they hit back, DidViewAppear gets called where the service call is not made, and DidViewLoad does not get called.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You store you response in a Object and check for its null value.

```
 ResponseObject mResponse;//your response data type

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_inbox, container, false);
        context = getActivity();

        //Get Messages From Cloud - web service call
        if (mResponse == null) {
            GetMessagesFromCloud();
        } else {
            //update UI
        }
    }

    //your response callback. I am not sure what are your callbacks so its just a hint
    public void onSucess(ResponseObject response) {
        mResponse = response;
    }
```

Comment: Thank you. That is another way of additional condition and making a web service call only when the condition met. But is there a better way that Android itself provides (just like I explained in my post with iOS)?